# How to convert xml value to a table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

The below code is returning only 6 rows with only 1st value. I want 6 rows with there respective values

```
    DECLARE @txml XML 
    SET @txml ='
    <row ch="&#x9;" unicode_value="9" cnt="3" />
    <row ch="&#xA;" unicode_value="10" cnt="5" />
    <row ch="&#xD;" unicode_value="13" cnt="5" />
    <row ch=" " unicode_value="32" cnt="962" />
    <row ch="&amp;" unicode_value="38" cnt="32" />
    <row ch="(" unicode_value="40" cnt="8" />
    '
    SELECT x.value('(/row/@cnt)[1]', 'int') AS cnt
    FROM  @txml.nodes('/row') AS tbl( x )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking first item value because that's how your XPath expression is defined: `'(row/@cnt)[1]'`

`[1]` states for first occurrence matching `row/@cnt` expression, what takes `cnt` attribute value from the first `<row>` element.

Change your query to:

```
SELECT x.value('@cnt', 'int') AS cnt
FROM  @txml.nodes('/row') AS tbl( x )
```

It will take `cnt` attribute value for current `<row>` element, not always the first one.

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11881)**

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was knowing that problem exists in '(row/@cnt)[1]' but didn't know how to write the correct code.

Comment: But for what if my xml is of type '  <root><ch> </ch><unicode_value>9</unicode_value><cnt>3</cnt><ch>
  </ch><unicode_value>10</unicode_value><cnt>5</cnt><ch>
  <ch>)</ch><unicode_value>41</unicode_value><cnt>8</cnt><ch>,</ch><unicode_value>44</unicode_value><cnt>234</cnt>
  </root>'